# Why does Javassist insist on looking for a default annotation value when one is explicitly specified?

Tags: javassist

I am using [Javassist](http://www.javassist.org) to add and modify annotations on a `package-info` "class".

In some cases, I need to deal with the following edge case.  Someone has (incorrectly) specified an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` annotation on the `package-info` package, but has not supplied a `value` attribute (which is [defined as being required](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapters.html#value%28%29)).  So it looks like this:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters // XXX incorrect; value() is required, but javac has no problem
package com.foobar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
```

In Javassist, this comes through slightly oddly.

The `javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation` representing the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` annotation does not have a member value (`getMemberValue("value")` returns `null`), as expected.

It is of course possible to add a `value()` member value, and that is what I've done:

```
if (adaptersAnnotation.getMemberValue("value") == null) {
    final ArrayMemberValue amv = new ArrayMemberValue(new AnnotationMemberValue(constantPool), constantPool);
    adaptersAnnotation.addMemberValue("value", amv);
    annotationsAttribute.addAnnotation(adaptersAnnotation);
}
```

In the code snippet above, I've created a new member value to hold an array of annotations, because the `value()` attribute of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` is an array of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.  I've specified its array type by trying to divine the Zen-like documentation's intent—it seems that if you supply another `MemberValue` that this `MemberValue` will somehow serve as the array's type.  In my case I want the type of the array to be `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, which is an annotation, so the only kind of `MemberValue` that seemed appropriate was `AnnotationMemberValue`.  So I've created an empty one of those and set it as the array type.

This works fine as far as it goes, as long as you stay "within" Javassist.

However, something seems to have gone wrong.  If I ask Javassist to convert all of its proprietary annotations into genuine Java `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`s, then when I try to access the `value()` attribute of this `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` annotation, Javassist tells me that there is no default value.  Huh?

In other words, that's fine—indeed there is not—but I have specified what I had hoped was a zero-length array (that is, the default value shouldn't be used; my explicitly specified zero-length array should be used instead):

```
final List<Object> annotations = java.util.Arrays.asList(packageInfoClass.getAnnotations());
for (final Object a : annotations) {
  System.out.println("*** class annotation: " + a); // OK; one of these is @XmlJavaTypeAdapters
  System.out.println("    ...of type: " + a.getClass()); // OK; resolves to XmlJavaTypeAdapters
  System.out.println("    ...assignable to java.lang.annotation.Annotation? " + java.lang.annotation.Annotation.class.isInstance(a)); // OK; returns true

  if (a instanceof XmlJavaTypeAdapters) {
    final XmlJavaTypeAdapters x = (XmlJavaTypeAdapters)a;
    System.out.println("    ...value: " + java.util.Arrays.asList(x.value())); // XXX x.value() throws an exception
  }
}
```

So why is Javassist looking for a default value in this case?

My larger issue is of course to handle this (unfortunately somewhat common) case where `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` is specified with no further information on it.  I need to add a `value` member value that can hold an array of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations.  I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this with Javassist.  As always, all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, it appears that in this particular case (to avoid a `NullPointerException` and/or a `RuntimeException`), you need to do this:

```
if (adaptersAnnotation.getMemberValue("value") == null) {
    final ArrayMemberValue amv = new ArrayMemberValue(constantPool);
    amv.setValue(new AnnotationMemberValue[0]);
    adaptersAnnotation.addMemberValue("value", amv);
    annotationsAttribute.addAnnotation(adaptersAnnotation);
}
```

Note in particular that I **deliberately omit the array type** when building the `ArrayMemberValue` (including one of any kind will result in an exception).  Then I explicitly set its value to an empty array of type `AnnotationMemberValue`.  Any other combination here will result in an exception.

Additionally, and very oddly, the last line in that `if` block is critical.  Even though in this particular case the annotation itself was found, and so hence was already present in the `AnnotationsAttribute`, **you must re-add it**.  If you do not, you will get a `RuntimeException` complaining about the lack of a default value.

I hope this helps other Javassist hackers.